# select max value from (select query)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, max

I've got a SQL statement which already works, but I want to add another subselect query which returns (MAX value of results) for the following subselect query,

```
(select  count(*) from users where `score` =8 and `uni` = t.uni)*8 as 'rscore',
```

here is my code

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test')or die ( mysqli_error($connect) ); 

$output = '';


 $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "select t.uni, 
(select  count(*) from users where `score` =8 and `uni` = t.uni)*8 as 'rscore',
 (select  count(*) from users where `uni` = t.uni) as 'total'
from users t group by t.uni
";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

 $output .= '
 ';
   $i=1;
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {


  echo '
   <tr>
    <td align="center">' . $i . '</td> 
    <td width="10%">'.$row["uni"].'</td>
    <td align="center">'.$row["rscore"].'</td>
    <td align="center">'.$row["total"].'</td>
   </tr>
  ';
  $i++; 
 }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Do you want record count or Max from the selected column?

Comment: `MAX()` function is used for getting `max` value of a column.

Comment: Which column's max value are you interested in?

Comment: I want to return (max value) of selected count query, not from a column.

Comment: max value of subquery (select  count(*) from users where `score` =8 and `uni` = t.uni)*8 as 'rscore',

Answer (score 3):

You could use an `conditional aggregation`, `count` and `max`

```
select  uni, sum( case when score  =8  then 1 else 0 end )*8 as rscore,
        count(*) total,
        max(my_col) my_max 
from  users
group by uni
```

**Ref:** 
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-max-function/
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/

Comment: What do you  mean " but not working"   you have an error?  .. show th error message  ... wrong result?  update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: I mean code you mentioned as an example, I checked the ref you mentioned but I did not find something useful about finding max value from subselect or subquery @scais Edge

Comment: add a proper data sample and the expected result